# Explicitly load multiple navigations at once in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In EF Core 7, you can explicitly load the navigation properties of an already loaded entity:

```cs
var obj = [... some entity ...];
foreach (var navigation in dbContext.Entry(obj).Navigations)
{
    if (SomeCriterion(obj, navigation))
    {
        await navigation.LoadAsync();
    }
}
```

However, this uses multiple queries - one query for each navigation property. Is it possible to load all those navigations in a single query?

I found many results about how those properties can be eagerly loaded (auto-include, .Include()). I also found how a single navigation can be loaded explicitly (.LoadAsync()). However, I could not find any results about explicitly loading multiple navigations at once.

**Context:**

My model contains a base class, say, `MyBase`. It has many derived classes and many of those are configured to use eager-loading, e.g., `builder.Navigation(x => x.Node).AutoInclude()`. I need to load a single derived object by id from the database:

```cs
var obj = await dbContext.Set<MyBase>().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstAsync();
```

In this query, EF Core adds one LEFT JOIN for each auto-included property of all derived types. There are about 30 derived classes and each class has roughly 2 auto-included properties, which means that the query has more than 64 LEFT JOINs. This reaches a limit in sqlite, so that sqlite refuses to execute the query. I do not want to change the configured limit, because it exists fpr a reason.

My idea is to first query the object without eager-loading, e.g., `.IgnoreAutoIncludes()`. This produces an object of the derived type. For this object, I explicitly load the properties that should have been eager-loaded:

```cs
var obj = await dbContext.Set<MyBase>().Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .IgnoreAutoIncludes().FirstAsync();
foreach (var navigation in dbContext.Entry(obj).Navigations)
{
    if (!navigation.IsLoaded && navigation.Metadata.IsEagerLoaded)
    {
        await navigation.LoadAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: `one query for each navigation property` yes, because there's no other way. You're loading related objects from *multiple* tables, not just one. There's no useful way to write *one* SQL query that returns different results from different tables. You could use a UNION ALL that returns *all* columns from all the 1st, 2nd, 3rd relations etc, with NULLs on other table's values and some extra field to differentiate types, but that's *very* inefficient and will probably result in bad execution plans. You can batch multiple such queries in a single script but you still need separate SELECT queries.

Comment: Why use explicit loading if you want all the properties? Why not use eager loading? Explicit loading is used when you only want to load specific relations. In this case you want to load all of them.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's a problem X and the attempted solution Y is to load some/all objects without relations, then explicitly load the relations for some or all of them. When that fails you ask about X, not the actual problem Y. What's the *actual* problem? Why not load everything from the start? Even if you want to fully load only a few objects it's probably faster to write a new LINQ query that does that

Comment: For example, load just the info you want to display to a grid with with `ctx.Customers.Where(...).Select(c=>new {c.Id,...})` and after the user selects some rows, load the full objects `ctx.Customers.Where(c=>selectedIds.Contains(c.Id)).Include(c=>c.Orders)...`

Comment: The auto-include makes it possible to load related stuff in a single query. So there is a way. I do not want to load all properties, but just a specific subset, that's why I added `SomeCriterion(...)` in the question. About XY: I have a TPH inheritance hierarchy and load my entity via base type. EF Core generates a query with one JOIN for each auto-include in any derived type. That's why I disable the auto-include for this query and then load the navigation properties just for the specific derived type.

Comment: What do you mean auto-include? Lazy loading? Or `Include` in the model? As for TPH, you're still describing Y. You still haven't explained why you don't load the full objects. If you want only a specific type, load that specific type.

Comment: As for the exact solution to the *comment question*, I already answered that in a previous comment. Run a new query on that DbSet using the IDs. Think, how would you solve the same problem in SQL? You'd write one query that JOINs all the related tables and filter by the IDs with `WHERE ID in (@id1,@id2,.....)`

Comment: We're still at Y0 though - why do you need to load all types (A,B,C) without relations but *one* type (C) with relations? Wouldn't it be better to load only A,B without relations and then C *with* them?

Comment: My problem is: I have a base class with many derived classes. Some of those derived classes are configured to use lazy-loading (`builder.Navigation(...).AutoInclude()`). I need to load a single entity by id, but I dont know its derived type. Therefore, I use `dbContext.Set<BaseClass>().First(x => x.Id == 123)`. This produces a query with one JOIN for each .AutoInclude() in any derived class, which does not perform well.

Comment: That's why I had the idea to load the entity using `.IgnoreAutoIncludes()` so that I receive an object of the derived type. However, I still need to fill the navigation properties.

Comment: Write that in the question itself, and explain the actual sequence. You retrieve a single object by ID and if it's a specific type, you want to retrieve that single object's full relations. Single vs multiple matters. The *statistics* probably matter too - if the "full" instances are the majority you could try to load the "full" type explicitly and if nothing is found, load the base without includes.

Comment: For example, in SQL you could write a single query with LEFT JOINs no matter the type, then map based on the result's discriminator. If the tables are properly indexed and don't contain multi-millions of rows each, this won't be expensive.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback. I edited the question and added the details.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to just write original query so it would include everything needed (with `Include`). If it is not an option you can try a bit hacky way relying on [tracked queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) and relationship fixup:

```cs
var obj = ...; // this should be atracked entity

var query = dbContext.TheEntites.AsTracking().Where(...); // the query to get object again

foreach (var navigation in dbContext.Entry(obj).Navigations)
{
    if (SomeCriterion(obj, navigation))
    {
        query = query.Include(navigation.Metadata.Name);    
    }
}

await query.ToListAsync(); // this should result in obj relations filled
```

Note that if you are not relying on info from the `obj` instance - you can use similar approach to generate the original query with conditional `Include`'s.

> This produces a query with one JOIN for each .AutoInclude() in any derived class, which does not perform well.

In some cases [`.AsSplitQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) can help with performance in case when multiple joins are needed.

Comment: From the comments it seems that only *one* object in a TPH hierarchy gets loaded by ID. If that object is a specific type, the relations are loaded. A single SQL with LEFT JOINs would produce the correct data, no matter the type. I wonder if EF can do that, then map based on a discriminator column

Comment: That is actually what happens. EF produces a single query with many LEFT JOINs. To be precise, it produces more than 64 LEFT JOINS, which reaches a limit in sqlite so that sqlite refuses to execute the query. I dont want to change the limit, because it is there for a reason.